# PyInstaller has trouble with flask.ext imports

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I want to compile my project with PyInstaller.  Importing from `flask.ext`, such as `from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`, doesn't seem to work right.  How can I import these libraries and still use PyInstaller?

Answer (score 3):

Using `flask.ext` is going to be deprecated then removed in upcoming versions of Flask.  It was only a temporary step for converting from an even *older* import system using namespace packages.  In fact, all `flask.ext.sqlalchemy` does is look for `flaskext.sqlalchemy` then `flask_sqlalchemy` anyway.  It's this "magic" lookup that is breaking PyInstaller's import detection.

The correct way to import Flask extensions now and in the future is to just import directly from the installed packages.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```